# Email not working with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, email, grep

I am trying to monitor our voip sip trunk carrier if it becomes unavailable i get an email from script below, the command in the script is working fine create log file in /tmp/checkpeers but script is not sending out email i have tried many options as they can be seen in the script below, i have also tested mail delivery agent is enable and i have sent out some test emails using email -s "test" me@me.com it works, can someone please help out with this.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check for Offline SIP Peers
#peername=vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine
rm -f /tmp/checkPeers
#/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep UNKNOWN >/tmp/checkPeers
#asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine | grep -v OK

asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine | grep -v OK >/tmp/checkpeers

if [ -s "/tmp/checkPeers" ]; then
mail -s "Vitelity Inbound SIP Connection OffLine please Check" me@me.com < /tmp/checkpeers
#[EMAIL="me@me.com"]me@me.com[/EMAIL] </tmp/checkpeers

#SUBJECT="Vitelity Inbound SIP Connection OffLine please Check"
#EMAILID="me@me.com" </tmp/checkPeers
#$SUBJECT
#$EMAILID

fi
```

Comment: Are you able to send an email from the command line using 'mail -s'?

Comment: Yes it works with mail -s no problem

Comment: How is the script being run? Note that the `asterisk` line will create `/tmp/checkpeers` (which may be empty and will fail a `-s` test), but you are removing and later testing for `/tmp/checkPeers`, which is a different file, though the `mail` command takes input from the lower-case file.

Comment: even if i comment rm -f /tmp/check.. it still does't sent out email, and i am running script manually sh monitorsip.sh, also the script has 755 permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the file you are creating doesn't match the file you're testing.  These are the lines I'm referring to.

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine | grep -v OK >/tmp/checkpeers
if [ -s "/tmp/checkPeers" ]; then
```

in the first you are creating the file as `/tmp/checkpeers`, but in the second, you are testing against `/tmp/checkPeers`.  Notice the difference in the lowercase `p` and uppercase `P`?  Since files in Linux are case-sensitive, these need to be the same.  Make sure the filenames match here and in other places in your script.

Good luck.

Comment: That was it boss you got it thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Further to @virtex's observation, I would avoid temp files altogether

```
data=$(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine | grep -v OK)

if [ -n "$data" ]; then
    subject="Vitelity Inbound SIP Connection OffLine please Check"
    recipients="me@me.com"

    echo "$data" | mail -s "$subject" "$recipients"
fi
```

If you're OK with temp files, then DRY and use a variable to hold the filename:

```
tmp=$(mktemp -t checkPeers.XXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp" EXIT            # remove when script exits

asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep vitel-inbound2/kdc_gatine | grep -v OK >"$tmp"

if [ -s "$tmp" ]; then
    mail -s "Vitelity Inbound SIP Connection OffLine please Check" me@me.com <"$tmp"
fi
```